# Concatenate arrays in liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am trying to concatenate three arrays in liquid/jekyll but in the final array (publications) I get only the elements of the first one (papers)

```
{% assign papers = (site.publications | where:"type","paper" | sort: 'date') | reverse %}
{% assign posters = (site.publications | where:"type","poster" | sort: 'date') | reverse %}
{% assign abstracts = (site.publications | where:"type","abstract" | sort: 'date') | reverse %}
{% assign publications = papers | concat: posters | concat: abstracts %}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that `posters` and `abstracts` are non-empty arrays? Double-check that by outputting them to the page separately.

Comment: What are `{{ pagers | inspect }}` and `{{ posters | inspect }}` outputs.

Comment: @KevinWorkman. I've double checked that. If I loop and output each array separately all elements are there

Comment: @DavidJacquel with pagers I guess you meant papers. Both outputs look like this:

[{ "path": "_publications/poster2016.markdown", "id": "/publications/poster2016", "output": "", "content": "", "relative_path": "_publications/poster2016.markdown", "url": "/publications/poster2016.html", "collection": "publications", "excerpt": "", "previous": { "path": "_publications/mb2016.markdown", "id": "/publications/mb2016", "output": "", "content": "", "relative_path": "_publications/mb2016.markdown", "url": "/publications/mb2016.html", "collection": "publications", "excerpt":..........

Comment: It's better if you update you question with this output, you can then format it nicely. ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### New answer

Jekyll now uses Liquid 4.x. So we can use the [concat](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/array-filters#concat) filter !

#### Old answer

`concat` filter is not part of current liquid gem (3.0.6) used by jekyll 3.2.1.

It will only be available in liquid 4 (https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/v4.0.0.rc3/lib/liquid/standardfilters.rb#L218).

I will probably be available for Jekyll 4.

In the meantime, this plugin can do the job :

```
=begin
  Jekyll filter to concatenate arrays
  Usage:
    {% assign result = array-1 | concatArray: array-2 %}
=end
module Jekyll
  module ConcatArrays

    # copied from https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/v4.0.0.rc3/lib/liquid/standardfilters.rb
    def concat(input, array)
      unless array.respond_to?(:to_ary)
        raise ArgumentError.new("concat filter requires an array argument")
      end
      InputIterator.new(input).concat(array)
    end

   class InputIterator
      include Enumerable

      def initialize(input)
        @input = if input.is_a?(Array)
          input.flatten
        elsif input.is_a?(Hash)
          [input]
        elsif input.is_a?(Enumerable)
          input
        else
          Array(input)
        end
      end

      def concat(args)
        to_a.concat(args)
      end

      def each
        @input.each do |e|
          yield(e.respond_to?(:to_liquid) ? e.to_liquid : e)
        end
      end
    end

  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::ConcatArrays)
```

Comment: Thanks, I installed the plugin following method 1 from here (https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/) and it works perfectly.

Comment: Good news: By now this is part of Jekyll (current version 3.5.2 uses liquid 4.0.0)